# Monodevelop crashes when I type the letter "o" instead of an integer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash, monodevelop

Working with Monodevelop has been a nightmare overall.  But among all the crashes, I have been able to recreate one of them reliably.

It seems like when I type "o" (the letter) when Monodevelop expects me to type an integer it will always crash.

**Examples:**

```
if (spriteRenderers.Length == o      <----*CRASH*

for (int i=o                         <----*CRASH*
```

Now, of course, this typically only happens when I've made a mistake, but it does seem to be causing the crash.

And by "crash" I mean that Monodevelop stops working, and I get an error message from Windows asking if I would like to force quit the application.  Upon re-opening Monodevelop it shows a blank white screen (every time).

The only fix I've found for the white screen is to delete the "Assembly-CSharp..." files in the project folder and then resync the Monodevelop project in Unity3D.  I sometimes have to repeat this up to 10 times before Monodevelop will work again, and about half the time I lose a significant amount of work as a result.

Has anyone else experienced something similar?  Any ideas on how to prevent this type of crash?

PS: It also tends to crash a lot when I'm typing "default" within a switch statement, but not every time like the "o" instance above.

Comment: You may have been down-voted for this question because it appears to be off topic of Stack Overflow at first blush, since it looks like you're making a general forum post about a specific product crashing. However, it appears to be possibly on topic since you are just looking for a way to prevent a common crash to a common developer tool. Hope you find what you need!

Comment: Thank you Joel.  I saw a lot of questions about Monodevelop crashing, but I'm new to Stackoverflow, so I might not understand what's appropriate =/

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. I can try compiling and I get the expected compiler error.

Comment: In Unity settings you can choose which MonoDevelop to use - maybe your pointing to an older version?

Answer (score 0):

If typing a specific letter crashes monodevelop there's certainly something going totally wrong here. First, confirm whether typing 'o' crashes monodevelop anywhere in any situation. Because I find it hard to believe that it crashes *only* when you type o where 0 is expected - because how would monodevelop know what is "expected" in a given situation? So unless that is confirmed, I assume this is not what is actually going on but rather something that you've came to conclude due to [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) (ie it happend two or three times by chance in a situation where you intended to type 0 rather than o).

That said, check if any keyboard shortcut has been assigned to the letter o. You may want to reset keyboard shortcuts to their default. In general you may want to reset all preferences just to ensure monodevelop is using safe defaults for everything. Also check any plugin you may have installed, and disable them if only for testing.

You should also try shutting down Unity, and only run monodevelop. Then create a standalone project in monodevelop (ie C# windows app) to see if the problem also appears in "regular app development mode".

Lastly, upgrade Unity. If you are already on 4.6, get the latest "patch release" from the download page. This might also give you an updated monodevelop.

If all of that does not help, you may want to try Xamarin - the latest version of monodevelop. You can integrate that with unity by installing its Unity plugins, but currently it will not allow you to debug with Unity. In any case it installs itself side-by-side, so you should at least try that to see whether that has a similar problem.

If all of that fails, consider that the problem may be with your system. For instance a tool might have set a global keyboard shortcut on the letter o. A virus scanner or system driver may somehow interfere. Or the whole system is just whacky, perhaps a trojan, a hardware failure, and so on. That is all rather speculative, so at this point it's a matter of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Learn!

It definitely doesn't crash every time I type "o", but I should have been more clear.  When I said "..when it expects a 0"  what I meant was, "...when it expects an integer".

Such as {int= }

I'm also familiar with the confirmation biased, but do not worry, I have tested this dozens of times to confirm, and it happens every time

I just tried testing this with Unity closed (per your request), and it still crashes.

I'm using the most recent version of Monodevelop that Unity currently works with

I might try out Xamarin or Virtual Studio. Thanks for the advice!